# Linq to XML to retrieve value based on Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-xml

I have a Linq to Xml query that needs to retrieve a value based on the attribute value of a particular node. I'm trying to retrieve a list of items and one of the nodes has an attribute that I can't seem to find a way to get the value.
Here's the XML:

```
<codelist-items>
    <codelist-item>
        <code>1</code>
        <name>
            <narrative>Planned start</narrative>
            <narrative xml:lang="fr">Début prévu</narrative>
        </name>
        <description>
            <narrative>
                The date on which the activity is planned to start, for example the date of the first planned disbursement or when physical activity starts.
            </narrative>
        </description>
    </codelist-item>
    <codelist-item>
        <code>2</code>
        <name>
            <narrative>Actual start</narrative>
            <narrative xml:lang="fr">Début réel</narrative>
        </name>
        <description>
            <narrative>
                The actual date the activity starts, for example the date of the first disbursement or when physical activity starts.
            </narrative>
        </description>
    </codelist-item>
</codelist-items>
```

I'm only displaying 2 items to keep it short. And here is my Linq query to try and retrieve the value from "name/narrative" where there is a "xml:lang='fr'" attribute:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(xmlFile);

var elements = from adt in xelement.Elements("codelist-items").Elements("codelist-item")
               select new ActivityDateType
               {
                   Code = (string)adt.Element("code"),
                   NameEng = (string)adt.Element("name").Element("narrative"),
                   NameFra = (string)adt.Element("name").Element("narrative[@xml:lang='fr']"),
                   Description = (string)adt.Element("description")
                };

return elements;
```

Anyone know how to get the value for NameFra?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use LINQ `FirstOrDefault()` with predicate that filters the element by its attribute value :

```
NameFra = (string)adt.Element("name")
                     .Elements("narrative")
                     .FirstOrDefault(o => (string)o.Attribute(XNamespace.Xml+"lang") == "fr"),
```

Or use `XPathSelectElement()` extension to execute your XPath expression which already contains attribute filtering logic :

```
NameFra = (string)adt.Element("name")
                     .XPathSelectElement("narrative[@xml:lang='fr']", nsmgr),
```

The latter can be simplified further to the following :

```
NameFra = (string)adt.XPathSelectElement("name/narrative[@xml:lang='fr']", nsmgr),
```

`nsmgr` assumed has previously been declared as follow :

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
```

`nsmgr` was needed because the XPath contains prefix `xml` (`XPathSelectElement()` complained when I use the overload which accepts just XPath string argument without namespace manager).

Comment: Thanks har07, that's exactly what I needed.